# how to stop SSRS prompting user name and password when deploying a report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a problem with deploying reports where i'm being asked to enter username and password and i don't know what is the username and password to use. i checked all similar questions on stack overflow before asking this question. i tried the WA in this MS article with no luck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

I tried also from configuration manager to run reporting server under windows account so i can use the account later when the dialog of username and password appears but the service fails to start. can someone please guide me step by step how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: I found the problem. NETWORK SERVICE account was missing modify permission for SSRS\ReportServer\RSTempFiles folder.

Comment: you should add this as an answer and accept it, this helps others find answers to similar questions. You might want to also review some of your other questions as none of them as marked as accepted even though some have answers that have been voted up.